# What is the gap between Sharepoint REST and Microsoft Graph APIs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

I am developing a software to keep track of changes to files and folders made in SharePoint. I am trying to figure out what API to use. My understanding is that Microsoft is giving more focus on Microsoft Graph API. I have been doing research on the differences between them. Based on older posts, it is my understanding that you couldn't do things with Graph API that you could do with SharePoint Rest APIs. At least that was the case in the past, and the goal was to build Graph API to a point that you use Graph API for all that. Here is a link to [Microsoft 365 podcast](https://www.m365devpodcast.com/e/sharepoint-api-and-microsoft-graph-with-jeremy-kelley-cathy-dew/).

What is the gap like now? If I want to keep track of changes to made to SharePoint files and folders, then what is the most effective way to get those events through SharePoint REST API or Graph API?

Thank you!

Comment: For tracking changes made to SharePoint files and folders, you are best using the out-of-the-box version history.